# Bounded input Bounded output stability for heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, heat-equation, stability

This is a [cross-post from Computational  Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20074/bounded-input-boundaed-output-stability-for-heat-equation-proof-or-counter-exam).

I am interested in proving or obtaining a counterexample to the following conjecture.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded open domain.  Let $u_d\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) \times \mathbb{R}^+$. Suppose $u\in L^2((0,\infty); H^1(\Omega))$ is the weak solution of 
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
  u_t- \nabla \cdot \nabla u &= 0&\,  \mathrm{in}\,& (\Omega\times \mathbb{R}^+) \\
  u &= u_d&\, \mathrm{on}\,& (\partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+)\\
  u &= 0&\, \mathrm{at}&\, (\Omega \times \{0\})
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Then there exists a constant $C$ dependent only on the domain $\Omega$ such that
$
\left\| u \right\|_{L^\infty((0,\infty); L^2(\Omega))} \le C \left\| u_d \right\|_{L^{\infty}((0,\infty); H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega))}.
$

I haven't been able to find many texts that treat the heat equation with time varying boundary conditions.  Also, feel free to change the Sobolev spaces if you need to.

Addendum #1 Response to Denis Serre.  Thanks for the response.  I would like to check my understanding.  To simplify things I am going to consider a 2-dimensional problem.

We modify the problem as follows.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as $\Omega = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:  x>0\}$

Suppose $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+; H^1(\Omega)) $ is the weak solution of the above initial boundary value problem.

Step #1, Laplace Transform in $t$.

$0=\tau U(\tau,x,\eta) - \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}y^2}  U(\tau,x,\eta) - \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}U(t,x,\eta)$

Step #2, Fourier transform in $y$.

$0 = \tau\, \mathcal{U}(\tau, x,\eta) + |\eta|^2 \mathcal{U}(\tau, x,\eta) - \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \mathcal{U}(\tau,x,\eta)$

Step #3

Solve the resulting ODE.

$\mathcal{U}(\tau, x,\eta) = \mathcal{U}_d(\tau, \eta) \exp(-x\sqrt{\tau+|\eta|^2)}$

Step #4

Estimate $L^2$ norm.

$\int_{x\in \mathbb{R}^+}|\mathcal{U}|^2\, \mathrm{d}x = \cdots =  |\mathcal{U}_d(\tau, \eta)|^2 \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\tau+|\eta|^2}} $

Step #5

Go back by Plancherel

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{(x,y)\in \Omega} |U(\tau, x,y)|^2 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y 
&= \int_{\eta\in \mathbb{R}} \int_{x\in \mathbb{R}^+} |\mathcal{U} (\tau,x,\eta)|^2 \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}\eta \\
&= \int_{\eta\in \mathbb{R}} |\mathcal{U}_d(\tau, \eta)|^2 \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\tau+|\eta|^2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\\
&= \int_{\eta\in \mathbb{R}} |\mathcal{U}_d(\tau,\eta)|^2 \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\tau+ |\eta|^2}} \frac{(1+|\eta|^2)^{1/4}}{(1+|\eta|^2)^{1/4}}\, \mathrm{d}\eta \\
&\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\tau}} \left\|U_d(\tau,\cdot)\right\|^2_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}
\end{align*}
$$

I honestly don't know how to apply Paley-Wiener here.  Any hints would be appreciated.  If I am totally off track, please let me know too.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to L.C.Evans' very large book?

Comment: Yes, I have it.  The AMS book that is titled "Partial Differential Equations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory of linear Intial-boundary value problem proceeds the following way. In your case, because of the zero initial condition, you may replace ${\mathbb R}^+$ by $\mathbb R$ and define $u\equiv0$, $u_d\equiv0$ for $t<0$. Then what matters is the special case where $\Omega$ is a half-space, say $\{x_d>0\}$. In this simpler situation, you can (and you must) perform a Fourier transform in the tangential variables $x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1}$, and a Laplace transform in time. You end up with an ODE, parametrized by the frequency variables $\eta\in{\mathbb R}^{d-1}$ and $\Re\tau>0$ :
$$\tau v+|\eta|^2v-\frac{d^2v}{dx_d^2}=0,\qquad v:=\hat u$$
with an ''initial'' data
$$v(\tau,\eta,0)=\hat u_d(\tau,\eta).$$
Here, $x_d\mapsto v$ is the unique square integrable solution over ${\mathbb R}^+$.

Write the explicit form of $v(\tau,\eta,\cdot)$, estimate its $L^2$-norm (or every $H^s$-norm you wish). Then go back by Plancherel and Paley-Wiener. You obtain an accurate estimate in weighted spaces $L^2(e^{-\gamma t}dt;L^2(\Omega))$.

The method is detailed in my book with S. Benzoni-Gavage, in the case of hyperbolic equations (like the wave equation), but it can be applied to any well-posed IBVP. It is also used to detect the well- or ill-posedness (key word : Lopatinskii condition).

Answer (score 1):

In the paper by [Weidermann, *Maximal regularity for parabolic equations with inhomogeneous boundary conditions in Sobolev spaces with mixed $L_p$−norm*, 2002,](http://www.ams.org/journals/era/2002-08-06/S1079-6762-02-00104-X/S1079-6762-02-00104-X.pdf) you can find in particular the estimate
$$
  \Vert u \Vert_{L^2 ([0, T]; H^2 (\Omega))}
+ \Vert u \Vert_{H^1 ([0, T]; L^2 (\Omega))}
\le C \Bigl(\Vert u_d \Vert_{L^2 ([0, T]; H^{3/2} (\partial \Omega))} + \Vert u_d \Vert_{H^{3/4} ([0, T]; L^2 (\partial \Omega))} \Bigr),
$$
provided that $u_d (0) = 0$ on $\{0\} \times \partial \Omega$.

This estimate implies an estimate in $L^\infty ([0, T]; L^2 (\Omega))$.
Compared to the question, remark that there we need some *regularity in time on the Dirichlet boundary condition*.

One way to obtain such estimates for linear problems with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions is to first construct an extension $v$ satisfying your initial and boundary condition with suitable estimate (this is called trace theory) and then apply the theory for homogeneous boundary conditions to the new function $u - v$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  I am going to go through the paper this weekend.  I haven't looked at it yet.  Do you know if the result can be extended from $L^{\infty}([0,T]; L^2(\Omega))$ to $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+; L^2(\Omega))$.  I ask because a lot of similar estimates use Gronwall's lemma/ inequality in such a way that the hidden constant goes to infinity exponentially as $T\to \infty$,